# timeout() operator not working in pipe Rxjs subject

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an Issue with timeout operator in subject.

my problem look like sample above, but I got all of source,

response:
observable: 1
observable: 2

url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ou5yp1?file=index.ts

```
import { Subject, from,Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {timeout} from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new Subject();
 subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observer: ${v}`),
   error: (e) => console.log(`There is an Error ${e}`)
  });
subject.pipe(timeout(2000));

const observable = new Observable( sub=> {
 sub.next( 1);
 setTimeout(()=> {
 sub.next(2)
 },5000)
})
observable.subscribe(subject);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have subscribed to wrong observable.

```
subject.pipe(timeout(2000));
```

The above line does not apply to subject itself, but instead returns a new observable which has 2 seconds timeout. So you should subscribe to this returned observable instead of subject itself. So your code should be:

```
subject.pipe(timeout(2000)).subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observer: ${v}`),
  error: (e) => console.log(`There is an Error ${e}`)
});
```